# How to convert 0:00:00 to 00:00:00 time format in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv, time

I am trying to convert time format 0:00:00 to 00:00:00 from my CSV file in SQLite. I have tried using time() but it would delete a time with any hour of a single digit (for example: 8:09:09 would be deleted, but the time frame between 10:00:00-23:59:59 is kept). Is there a way to convert this time frame in SQLite or would it be easier to convert it in my CSV file? How would I convert the time format in my CSV file, if applicable? I hope this question is clear as I am new here. I posted my table and the code here to illustrate the issue I am facing.

Table 1:

| ID | BEFORE_DATE | BEFORE_TIME | AFTER_DATE | AFTER_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81 | 2020-01-03 | 18:01:09 | 2020-01-03 | 22:44:12 |
| 8 | 2020-05-09 | 8:01:09 | 2020-05-09 | 13:44:12 |
| 9 | 2020-02-09 | 16:09:23 | 2020-02-09 | 13:00:00 |

My goal:

Table 2

| ID | BEFORE_DATE | BEFORE_TIME | AFTER_DATE | AFTER_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 81 | 2020-01-03 | 18:01:09 | 2020-01-03 | 22:44:12 |
| 8 | 2020-05-09 | 8:01:09 | 2020-05-09 | 13:44:12 |

The problem here is that ID 8 won't show. Instead, only ID 81 shows.

My current code:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
from table1
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE BEFORE_DATE=AFTER_DATE AND TIME(BEFORE_TIME) < TIME(AFTER_TIME);
```

Comment: I have edited my question with my table and current code.

Comment: For ID=8, the before date is greater than after date, are you sure about it or it's a typo?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. It was a typo on my end while writing the question and table.

Comment: No 9
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/sqlite-date-function/

Comment: Do yourself a favor and update the time columns in your table with the proper time format: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=278c09895a9e75517f148b12c299af10 Then you can use SQLite's functions or compare times directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is only with the missing 0 from the hours part, you may check the length of the time string and add that missing 0 for times with length =7, try the following:

```
With Fixed_Times AS
(
  SELECT ID, BEFORE_DATE,
       Case When length(BEFORE_TIME)=7 Then ('0' || BEFORE_TIME) Else BEFORE_TIME End AS BEFORE_TIME,
       AFTER_DATE,
       Case When length(AFTER_TIME)=7 Then ('0' || AFTER_TIME) Else AFTER_TIME End AS AFTER_TIME
  FROM table1
)

SELECT * FROM Fixed_Times
WHERE BEFORE_DATE <= AFTER_DATE AND BEFORE_TIME < AFTER_TIME
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=9be58d2d75ac3ae151db4392b8c0ac4a).

To create another table and insert the results to it (as you did in your question), try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
With Fixed_Times AS
(
  SELECT ID, BEFORE_DATE,
       Case When length(BEFORE_TIME)=7 Then ('0' || BEFORE_TIME) Else BEFORE_TIME End AS BEFORE_TIME,
       AFTER_DATE,
       Case When length(AFTER_TIME)=7 Then ('0' || AFTER_TIME) Else AFTER_TIME End AS AFTER_TIME
  FROM table1
)
SELECT * FROM Fixed_Times
WHERE BEFORE_DATE <= AFTER_DATE AND BEFORE_TIME < AFTER_TIME;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=3b465033404d91738d05f91d26519e7e).

To update the original table (table1) and fix the time format, try the following:

```
Update table1 set BEFORE_TIME =
       Case When length(BEFORE_TIME)=7 Then ('0' || BEFORE_TIME) Else BEFORE_TIME End,
       AFTER_TIME =
       Case When length(AFTER_TIME)=7 Then ('0' || AFTER_TIME) Else AFTER_TIME End;
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=64bef444a002e1a55502fe206df260cf).

Comment: It did work! Thank you! But how would I save this new time format then? (For Table 1) Would I do this `code` CREATE TABLE Fixed_Times AS FROM table1  SELECT ID, ...  ?

Comment: Ok, Just a minute, I'll update the answer according to this new requirement.

Comment: The last code you wrote was much better and more simple! It did fix the time format. Thank you very much!